# is there a way to change Button style direclty from a callback function onPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

I'm new in React Native, and I'm trying to make Button selected and the others just not selected, so as in web, I remove all selected class from all the buttons, then give the class to the selected one.

How can I do that here?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html

Comment: this is not helpful

Comment: Please, if you need help provide us some code to better understand how you are styling buttons. Are they components? Are they taken from another library? Are they created by you? How you select the first with styles or with a prop like "selected = {true}"?

Comment: If you want to use jquery-style, you should not probably use react. What you are trying to do is probably achievable just using CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question, one way to solve it is maintaining a state in your component constructor like this: `this.state={selected: 0}`. The integer of the state `selected` will be the index of the currently pressed button among the buttons in the same container.

Assuming you are mapping out the buttons with something like

```
buttons.map((button, index) => 
<Button>
 <Text>
  Some Text
 </Text>
</Button>)
```

You should be able to attach a `key` in every `Button` tag with the `index`. Then you can call a component method in each `Button` that makes use of the `key` to set the state's `selected` to the `index` of the button being pressed. And finally you can render different styles based on the currently selected button by checking with value in the state.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native'


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {buttonClick: false};
  }
  onClickButton() {
    this.setState(previousState => {
        return {buttonClick: !previousState.buttonClick};
      });
  }
  render() {
    const cssButtonStyle = (this.state.buttonClick)? 'darkslateblue' : 'mediumturquoise';
    console.log(this.state.buttonClick);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Button
        color={cssButtonStyle}
        onPress={(event) => this.onClickButton(event)}
        title="Learn More"
        accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)
```

This is what can be achieved actually with React-Native.
It has basic customizations only.(https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button).

Use the above code in this place:
http://dabbott.github.io/react-native-web-player/

You can use this npm package for more customizations:
https://github.com/ide/react-native-button